# USBIP closes bus connections while requesting the data

Tags: networking, 18.04, usb

I have a turtlebot3 and Astra Stereo s 3d

I am exporting the usb port of turtlebot3 over the network and attaching it to a remote PC for getting the data for further processing.

When I try to get single type of data i.e. RGB or depth information everything work fine. But when I request both of them at the same time, RGB port gets closed and now data arrives and the camera driver stops working.

The result of lsusb astra camera:

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 2bc5:0508  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2bc5:0608
```

So I have to attach both of them.

On remote PC

> usbip list -r host_ip

```
Exportable USB devices
======================
 - 192.168.0.223
    1-1.3.2: unknown vendor : unknown product (2bc5:0508)
           : /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2
           : Miscellaneous Device / ? / Interface Association (ef/02/01)

    1-1.3.1: unknown vendor : unknown product (2bc5:0608)
           : /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1
           : (Defined at Interface level) (00/00/00)
           :  0 - Vendor Specific Class / unknown subclass / unknown protocol (ff/00/00)
```

So the device with tag 1-1.3.2 gets closed when getting the both datastreams.

Any helps/suggestion/thoughts will really be appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm. I use USBIP on 19.10, and it works properly. Perhaps it's an issue with the camera?

Comment: Also, try using the `--debug`  flag on both the server and client to get more useful output from both.

Comment: @user535733 are you getting multiple datastreams?
I have rgb data stream and depth data as well which is coming from the port. So only one at a time is accessed remotely but work fine on a local machine.

Comment: Many simultaneous devices and streams in the past on 19.04, including a camera. Just one today on 19.10.